# How to write unit test case in jasmine?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

```
Flag(a) {
           let element=this.selected.filter(item => item.a=== a)
           return element.length > 1 ? true : false;
        }
```

Not sure how to write a unit test case for the above function. Can you please help

Comment: I would recommend https://shashankvivek-7.medium.com/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A test case consists always of 3 steps:

- Preparation
- Execution
- Verification

In your case this means:

- Preparation: set the value of `this.selected`
- Execution: call Flag with a defined a
- Verification: check the function return false

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy:

```
it('should run #Flag(a) method', () => {
  component.selected = [{ someKey1: 'someValue1' }, { someKey2: 'someValue2' }];
  const val = 'someValue1';
  spyOn(component, 'Flag').and.callThrough();
  component.Flag(val);
  expect(component.Flag).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```